# Modify user in openLdap via bash script

Tags: linux, bash, script, bash-scripting, openldap

Can you please help me put this command into if statement (bash scripting):

$ ldapmodify -D  -h 
password: [enter password]
dn: cn=vipb,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: memberUid
memberUid: fred

I tried to do it like this, but it is not working:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $1 = "blue" ] ; then
ldapmodify  -D "cn=admin,dc=blue,dc=com" -w "Blue123" dn:cn=Blue-group,ou=Blue,dc=blue,dc=com changetype: modify add: memberUid memberUid: testblue
fi
```

Also tried this:

#!/bin/bash

```
if [ $1 = "blue" ] ; then
        ldapmodify  -D "cn=admin,dc=blue,dc=com" -w "Blue123"
        dn:cn=Blue-group,ou=Blue,dc=blue,dc=com
        changetype: modify
        add: memberUid
        memberUid: testblue
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell scripts do not imitate keyboard input; they start programs, and wait for those programs to finish. The lines below ldapmodify do not become its input but are separate commands.

If you want to provide input to ldapmodify you need to specifically use script syntax to do that – e.g. `<<` "heredoc":

```bsh
if [ $1 = "blue" ] ; then
    ldapmodify -D whatever -w whatever <<'END'
dn: cn=foo
add: member
member: cn=bar
END
fi
```

or pipe it from another command:

```bsh
if [ $1 = "blue" ] ; then
    (echo "dn: cn=foo"
    echo "add: member"
    echo "member: cn=bar") | ldapmodify -D whatever -w whatever
fi
```